# Debug Web-application remotely

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have Web-application working code. I had put it using Remote Desktop Connection. That is not working there. Is there any option to enable debugging in Visual Studio 2008. Please help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to: Set Up Remote Debugging:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx

Comment: This means we can't debug web-application!

Comment: @MayP - I was successfully debugging web applications remotely. Just attach your debugger to ASP.NET worker process. I can't tell you what's wrong with IIS7 without ANY information. Check your logs / event viewer first then ask a different question with all the relevant information included.